# How to extend the curses window class in Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, class, extend, curses, python-curses

I would like to extend the `curses` built-in window class that is created by calling `curses.newwin()`.

However, I am hard-pressed to find out the actual name of that class that should replace the `¿newwin?` placeholder below.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import curses

class Window(curses.¿newwin?):

    def __init__(self, title, h, w, y, x):
        super().__init__(h, w, y, x)
        self.box()
        self.hline(2, 1, curses.ACS_HLINE, w-2)
        self.addstr(1, 2, title)
        self.refresh()

def main(screen):
    top_win = Window('Top window', 6, 32, 3, 6)
    top_win.addstr(3, 2, 'Test string added.')
    top_win.refresh()
    ch = top_win.getch()

# MAIN
curses.wrapper(main)
```

Comment: From the documentation, it doesn't look like the curses window class is directly part of the public API. Rather, the some of the documented functions return semi-opaque "window" objects which have some documented methods, without their types being specified. Have you considered using encapsulation rather than inheritance for your class? If you write an appropriate `__getattr__` method a lot of what you show in your example would just work.

Answer (score 2):

So I went for **encapsulation rather than inheritance,** which is like writing one's own API. I also applied the [global class pattern](https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2010/10/20/a-globals-class-pattern-for-python/), which is [discussed in a separate SE question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45052970/2192488).

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import curses

class win:
    pass

class Window:

    def __init__(self, title, h, w, y, x):
        self.window = curses.newwin(h, w, y, x)
        self.window.box()
        self.window.hline(2, 1, curses.ACS_HLINE, w-2)
        self.window.addstr(1, 2, title)
        self.window.refresh()

    def clear(self):
        for y in range(3, self.window.getmaxyx()[0]-1):
            self.window.move(y,2)
            self.window.clrtoeol()
        self.window.box()

    def addstr(self, y, x, string, attr=0):
        self.window.addstr(y, x, string, attr)

    def refresh(self):
        self.window.refresh()

def main(screen):
    win.top = Window('Top window', 6, 32, 3, 6)
    win.top.addstr(3, 2, 'Test string added.')
    win.top.refresh()
    ch = win.top.getch()

# MAIN
curses.wrapper(main)
```