# Can Python3 class instances be forced to be global objects at initialisation?

Tags: python-3.x, class, oop, initialization, global-variables

Even though global Python objects tend to be bad, I more or less forced to use them with module `curses`. I currently have this:

```
class Window:
    def __init__(self, title, h, w, y, x):
        self.window = curses.newwin(h, w, y, x)
        self.window.box()
        self.window.hline(2, 1, curses.ACS_HLINE, w-2)
        self.window.addstr(1, 2, title)
        self.window.refresh()

global top_win
top_win = Window('Top window', 6, 32, 3, 6)
```

I am wondering whether it would be possible to get rid of the `global` line by adding something to the class definition or initialisation?

```
class Window:
    def __init__(self, title, h, w, y, x):
        # Some global self magic
        self.window = curses.newwin(h, w, y, x)
        self.window.box()
        self.window.hline(2, 1, curses.ACS_HLINE, w-2)
        self.window.addstr(1, 2, title)
        self.window.refresh()

top_win = Window('Top window', 6, 32, 3, 6)
```

Comment: No, you can't. Classes have no control over what kind of references are created to them.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Obviously, you are absolutely right! I guess, I was rather looking for something like the [**global class pattern**](https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2010/10/20/a-globals-class-pattern-for-python/).

Answer (score 0):

### Global class pattern

Despite the reflexive downvotes whenever the word `global` is seen, I resolved my issue anyhow by applying the [*equally controversial* **global class pattern**](https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2010/10/20/a-globals-class-pattern-for-python/).

```
class win:
    pass

class Window:
    def __init__(self, title, h, w, y, x):
        self.window = curses.newwin(h, w, y, x)
        self.window.box()
        self.window.hline(2, 1, curses.ACS_HLINE, w-2)
        self.window.addstr(1, 2, title)
        self.window.refresh()

win.top = Window('Top window', 6, 32, 3, 6)
```

This results in `win.top` being accessible anywhere in my Python script, just like any `global` variable would have been, but then nice and neat in a more controlled manner.

This is quite handy for defining new `curses` windows inside the `main()` routine which is typically wrapped inside a `curses.wrapper(main)`. Follow this link for a [full blown Python3 `curses` example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45052355/2192488).